# Laravel validator for nested array

Tags: php, laravel

Am using the Laravel Validator class to do some basic validation on an array.

My array :

```
$employee['name']='name';
$employee['address']='address';
$employee['department']['name']='deptname';
$employee['department']['address']='deptaddress';
```

I have the validation rules as below:

```
$rules = array(
    'name'=> 'required',
    'address' => 'required'
)
```

And the custom messages as below :

```
$messages = array(
     'name.required' => 'Employee Name is required',
     'address.required' => 'Address is required'
)
```

I will use `Validator::make($employee, $rules, $messages);`

How do I write the rule and messages for `$employee[department]['name']` and `$employee[department]['address']` using same rules and messages variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use dot notation for nested array:

```
department.name
department.address
```

Comment: May be you can surely help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892058/laravel-sometimes-validator-fails-with-nested-arrays. 'sometimes' validator is not working with nested arrays.

Comment: Well, currently it's impossible to do, but I'm gonna make a pull request to fix this issue. Only then will you be able to make it work.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk any idea how to do it in Laravel 4?

Comment: Given the answer was given in April 2014 it should work in L4 ;)

Comment: What if we are having arrays in department. like
department[0]['name'];  
department[0]['address'];  
department[1]['name'];  
department[1]['address'];

Comment: @KapilVerma depending on the Laravel version - in 5.2+ you can use `department.*.name`, otherwise write custom rule https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/releases#laravel-5.2