# Laravel 'sometimes' validator fails with nested arrays

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

Am using the Laravel `Validator` class to do some basic validation on an array.

My array :

```
$employee['name']='name';
$employee['address']='address';
$employee['department']['department_name']='deptname';
$employee['department']['department_address']='deptaddress';
```

I have the validation rules as below:

```
$rules = array(
    'name'=> 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
    'department.department_name' => 'sometimes|required'
)
```

And the custom messages as below :

```
$messages = array(
     'name.required' => 'Employee Name is required',
     'address.required' => 'Address is required'
     'department.department_name.required' => 'Department name is required'
)
```

I will use `Validator::make($employee, $rules, $messages);`

As per my rules, `department_name` should be validated if and only if it is present in the array. But currently the `Validator` is not validating `department_name` when its present and blank. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I sent pull request to the framework, so when accepted I'll leave you a comment

Comment: it has been months since this bug was pointed out..and fixed. hopefully your pr will be accepted soon @dezco. thank you

Comment: also documentation is wrong on how to implement the `sometimes` rule as it indicates to use `sometimes|required`, but `required` take precedence and makes `sometimes` pointless.

Comment: In 4.1.* this error still occurs. @JarekTkaczyk, can you post the pull request?

Comment: @AlwinKesler I guess this was the one https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4076

Answer (score 1):

You are going a bit wrong here see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays) here

it is mentioned there If I have `$photos['profile']` then my validation will go like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'photos.profile' => 'required|image',
]);
```

From the above example, In your case it should be like this

```
$rules = array(
    'name'=> 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
    'employee.department.department_name' => 'sometimes|required'
)
```

Since you have array like this `$employee['department']['department_name']`

So does the `$message` will go like this

```
$messages = array(
     'name.required' => 'Employee Name is required',
     'address.required' => 'Address is required'
     'employee.department.department_name.required' => 'Department name is required'
)
```